# Hide controls in FlowDocumentReader

Tags: coding-style, customization, flowdocumentreader

Is it possible to hide controls at the bottom like zoom slider, page navigation etc in FlowDocumentReader? It seems that only search can be hidden through the IsFindEnabled property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you have to edit the default template - this is easy to do in Blend but I don't know how to do it in VS. I've done this before though, it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 18):

Just use a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` instead and set its `IsToolBarVisible` property to false.

Comment: I do want to use FlowDocumentReader toolbar features, just don't want buil-in toolbar to be visible.

Comment: FlowDocumentScrollViewer doesn't provide pagination feature.